# How to plot all the xaxis values in a df.plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this df:

```
      CODE         MONTH    PP
24    000136       Enero   57.9
25    000136     Febrero  124.3
26    000136       Marzo  147.7
27    000136       Abril   71.5
28    000136        Mayo   13.2
     ...         ...    ...
```

I'm plotting the figure with this code:

```
fig = plt.figure('Graphic', figsize=(30,15), dpi=150)
    
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.25, 0.60, 0.60])

df.plot(x='MONTH',y='PP',style='--o',color='black',linewidth=8,marker='o',markersize=12, ax=ax1)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(min_n_ticks=12))
```

I want to see all the 12 values of the months in my xaxis figure but i only got 6 of them in the figure.

I tried with `ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(min_n_ticks=12))` but it only plot the ticks, not the values in the xaxis.

Do you know how can i plot all the xaxis values?
I can only use a df.plot

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x-axis scale is automatically displayed, so add the number of pieces you wish to display to the x-axis setting. This will display 12 months. The missing data is added as appropriate.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure('Graphic', figsize=(20,10), dpi=150)
    
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.25, 0.60, 0.60])

df.plot(x='MONTH',y='PP',style='--o',color='black',linewidth=8,markersize=12, xticks=range(12), ax=ax1)
plt.show()
```

[image]